# Adding Multiple UITapGestureRecognizers to single view (Cocos2d)

Tags: uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am adding the following code in the onEnter method.

```
doubleTapRecognizer_ = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer_.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecognizer_.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer_];
```

I have multiple instances of this class,  but the only one that gets it's selector called is the last instance added.  The [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/gestureRecognizers) leads me to believe that it is possible to add more than one UIGestureRecognizer to a single view.  The property "gestureRecognizers" returns an NSArray.

In fact I already have a UIPanGestureRecognizer working with the same view from another class.  So I am getting at least two UIGestureRecognizers to work at once.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add multiple gesture recognizers to the same view. What you can't (easily) do is add multiple instances of the same gesture recognizer type (pan, swipe, double-tap, etc) to the same view.

Why?

Because as soon as the first gesture recognizer recognizes the gesture (double tap in this case) it cancels all touch events. Therefore the remaining gesture recognizers will never finish recognition, and will never fire their events.

You do not need more than one gesture recognizer of the same type. In your case, once you've received the double-tap event, it's up to you to signal the right object that it was double-tapped. Use the recognizer's position and other attributes to find, for example, the sprite that was double-tapped and then have it do whatever it needs to do.

For that reason it's good design to let the gestures be recognized by a higher-level node in your scene hierarchy (ie the UI layer) which then passes on the events to the appropriate nodes, or simply ignores it.

Comment: Your solution sounds great and will be easy to implement, but for the sake of learning what's the point of doubleTapRecognizer_.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;  Isn't that supposed to turn off touch canceling?

Answer (score 9):

In order to add more than one `UIGestureRecognizer` onto the same view, you need to set the `delegate` property of the gesture recognizers you added onto the view and implement the following method in the delegate:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

By the way above, you can add multiple gesture recognizers onto the same view, no matter whether the gesture recognizers are the same type or not.

For example, you can add two `UITapGestureRecognizer` onto the same view and the callbacks of the two tap gesture recognizers will be called. And the last added callback will be called first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sometimes we really need to add a second gesture recognizer of the same type with an already existing gesture recognizer. For example, for an `MKMapView`, there is already a pinch gesture on it, and I want to do some other stuff when I zoom the map by doing pinch gesture. In this case, I need to add another pinch gesture recognizer on to `MKMapView` and simultaneously make the existing pinch gesture recognizer work.

Comment: Thanks for this! I agree w @HongchaoZhang the use case does exist where simply running a function call from another method doesn't cut it.